# Similar to jQuery .closest() but traversing descendants?

Tags: jquery

Is there a function similar to `jQuery` `.closest()` but for traversing descendants and returning only closest ones?

I know that there is `.find()` function, but it returns all possible matches, not closest.

**Edit:**

Here is definition of closest *(at least for me)*:

In first place all childrens are traversed, then each individuals childrens are traversed.

In example given below `id='2'` is closest `.closest` descendants of `id="find-my-closest-descendant"`

```
<div id="find-my-closest-descendant">
    <div>
        <div class="closest" Id='1'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="closest" Id='2'></div>
</div>
```

Please see [JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/manishtpatel/2gaLx/6/).

Comment: What about `.find("filter here").eq(0)`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard well if it does a depth-first traversal then the zero'th element in the result list might not be the "closest", depending on what "closest" means.

Comment: @Pointy isn't it the same as `:first` filter?

Comment: No, I don't think so - the issue is that ":first" and ".eq(0)" refer to the DOM order, but if "closest" means "fewest DOM nodes away" then a "grandchild" of the first child would be returned instead of a later "child" that matches the selector.  I'm not 100% sure that's what the OP is about of course.

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin what exactly do that for you: http://plugins.jquery.com/closestDescendant/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to your definition of `closest`, I've written the following plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.closest_descendent = function(filter) {
        var $found = $(),
            $currentSet = this; // Current place
        while ($currentSet.length) {
            $found = $currentSet.filter(filter);
            if ($found.length) break;  // At least one match: break loop
            // Get all children of the current set
            $currentSet = $currentSet.children();
        }
        return $found.first(); // Return first match of the collection
    }    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Unlike the jQuery `.closest()` function, this matches the element it was called on as well.  See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzZvY/).  By changing it to  `$currentSet = this.children(); // Current place` it will start with it's children instead [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzZvY/2/)

Comment: JQuery's closest() can also be matched to the current element.

Answer (score 136):

If by "closest" descendant you mean the first child then you can do:

```
$('#foo').find(':first');
```

Or:

```
$('#foo').children().first();
```

Or, to look for the first occurrence of a specific element, you could do:

```
$('#foo').find('.whatever').first();
```

Or:

```
$('#foo').find('.whatever:first');
```

Really though, we need a solid definition of what "closest descendant" means.

E.g.

```
<div id="foo">
    <p>
        <span></span>
    </p>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Which `<span>` would `$('#foo').closestDescendent('span')` return?

Comment: thanks @999 for detailed answer, my expectation of decedent is first all childrens are traversed, then each individuals childrens. In example you given, second span would be returned

Comment: So breath-first, not depth-first

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd be interested to know whether `$('#foo').find('.whatever').first();` is "breadth-first" or "depth-first"

Comment: The one problem with this solution is that jQuery will find ALL matching criteria and then return the first one.  While the Sizzle engine is fast, this represents unnecessary extra searching.  There's no way to short-circuit the search and stop after the first match is found.

Comment: These examples all select depth-first descendants, not breadth-first, so these can't be used to solve the original question. In my testing they all returned the first span, not the second.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `find` with the `:first` selector:

```
$('#parent').find('p:first');
```

The above line will find the first `<p>` element in the descendants of `#parent`.

Comment: I think this is what the OP wanted, no plugin required. This will select the first matching element in the descendants of the selected element, for *each* selected element. So if you have 4 matches with your original selection, you could end up with 4 matches using the `find('whatever:first')`.

Answer (score 3):

What about this approach?

```
$('find-my-closest-descendant').find('> div');
```

This "direct child" selector works for me.

Comment: the OP specifically ask for something that traverses descendants, which this answer does not. This might be a good answer, but not for this particular question.

Comment: @KjetilNordin Maybe that's because the question was edited since my answer. Moreover, the definition of closest descendant is still not so clear, at least to me.

Comment: I definitely agree. closest descendant could mean so many things. Easier with parent in this case, where there is always a single parent to elements, on each level. And you're right about possible edits as well. I see now that my comment wasn't helpful in any way, especially since there already was a statement of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone's looking for a pure JS solution (using ES6 instead of jQuery), here's the one I use:

```
Element.prototype.QuerySelector_BreadthFirst = function(selector) {
    let currentLayerElements = [...this.childNodes];
    while (currentLayerElements.length) {
        let firstMatchInLayer = currentLayerElements.find(a=>a.matches && a.matches(selector));
        if (firstMatchInLayer) return firstMatchInLayer;
        currentLayerElements = currentLayerElements.reduce((acc, item)=>acc.concat([...item.childNodes]), []);
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for bringing your answer to my attention! You're right, looking back at my own, it feels like it's trying to be too clever and actually awkward (running `matches` twice also irks me quite a bit). +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you have to define what "closest" means.  If you mean the descendant node matching your criteria that is the shortest distance away in terms of parental links, then using ":first" or ".eq(0)" won't necessarily work:

```
<div id='start'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span class='target'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class='target'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In that example, the second ".target" `<span>` element is "closer" to the "start" `<div>`, because it's only one parental hop away.  If that's what you mean by "closest", you'd need to find the minimum distance in a filter function. The result list from a jQuery selector is always in DOM order.

Maybe:

```
$.fn.closestDescendant = function(sel) {
  var rv = $();
  this.each(function() {
    var base = this, $base = $(base), $found = $base.find(sel);
    var dist = null, closest = null;
    $found.each(function() {
      var $parents = $(this).parents();
      for (var i = 0; i < $parents.length; ++i)
        if ($parents.get(i) === base) break;
      if (dist === null || i < dist) {
        dist = i;
        closest = this;
      }
    });
    rv.add(closest);
  });
  return rv;
};
```

That's sort-of a hack plugin because of the way it builds the result object, but the idea is that you've got to find the shortest parental path out of all the matching elements you find.  This code biases towards elements leftward in the DOM tree because of the `<` check; `<=` would bias rightwards.

Answer (score 0):

I cooked up this, no implementation for positional selectors (they need more than just `matchesSelector`) yet:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TL4Bq/3/

```
(function ($) {
    var matchesSelector = jQuery.find.matchesSelector;
    $.fn.closestDescendant = function (selector) {
        var queue, open, cur, ret = [];
        this.each(function () {
            queue = [this];
            open = [];
            while (queue.length) {
                cur = queue.shift();
                if (!cur || cur.nodeType !== 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (matchesSelector(cur, selector)) {
                    ret.push(cur);
                    return;
                }
                open.unshift.apply(open, $(cur).children().toArray());
                if (!queue.length) {
                    queue.unshift.apply(queue, open);
                    open = [];
                }
            }
        });
        ret = ret.length > 1 ? jQuery.unique(ret) : ret;
        return this.pushStack(ret, "closestDescendant", selector);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

There is probably some bugs though, didn't test it very much.

Answer (score 0):

Rob W's answer didn't quite work for me. I adapted it to this which did work.

```
//closest_descendent plugin
$.fn.closest_descendent = function(filter) {
    var found = [];

    //go through every matched element that is a child of the target element
    $(this).find(filter).each(function(){
        //when a match is found, add it to the list
        found.push($(this));
    });

    return found[0]; // Return first match in the list
}
```

Comment: For me this looks exactly like `.find(filter).first()`, only slower ;)

Comment: Yep you're right. I wrote this when I was still pretty new to coding. I think I'll delete this answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following to include the target itself if it matches the selector:

```
    var jTarget = $("#doo");
    var sel = '.pou';
    var jDom = jTarget.find(sel).addBack(sel).first();
```

Markup:

```
<div id="doo" class="pou">
    poo
    <div class="foo">foo</div>
    <div class="pou">pooo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin returns the nth closest descendants.

```
$.fn.getNthClosestDescendants = function(n, type) {
  var closestMatches = [];
  var children = this.children();

  recursiveMatch(children);

  function recursiveMatch(children) {
    var matches = children.filter(type);

    if (
      matches.length &&
      closestMatches.length < n
    ) {
      var neededMatches = n - closestMatches.length;
      var matchesToAdd = matches.slice(0, neededMatches);
      matchesToAdd.each(function() {
        closestMatches.push(this);
      });
    }

    if (closestMatches.length < n) {
      var newChildren = children.children();
      recursiveMatch(newChildren);
    }
  }

  return closestMatches;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution (I wanted all closest descendants, i.e. breadth first + all matches regardless of which level it exists), here's what I ended up doing:

```
var item = $('#find-my-closest-descendant');
item.find(".matching-descendant").filter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.parent().closest("#find-my-closest-descendant").is(item);
}).each(function () {
    // Do what you want here
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution (using ES6).

```
export function closestDescendant(root, selector) {
  const elements = [root];
  let e;
  do { e = elements.shift(); } while (!e.matches(selector) && elements.push(...e.children));
  return e.matches(selector) ? e : null;
}
```

---

### Example

Considering the following structure:

```
div                 == $0
├── div             == $1
│   ├── div
│   ├── div.findme  == $4
│   ├── div
│   └── div
├── div.findme      == $2
│   ├── div
│   └── div
└── div             == $3
    ├── div
    ├── div
    └── div
```

```
closestDescendant($0, '.findme') === $2;
closestDescendant($1, '.findme') === $4;
closestDescendant($2, '.findme') === $2;
closestDescendant($3, '.findme') === null;
```

```js
function closestDescendant(root, selector) {
  const elements = [root];
  let e;
  do { e = elements.shift(); } while (!e.matches(selector) && elements.push(...e.children));
  return e.matches(selector) ? e : null;
}

const [$0, $1, $2, $3, $4] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(x => document.querySelector(`#e${x}`));

console.log(closestDescendant($0, '.findme')); // $2
console.log(closestDescendant($1, '.findme')); // $4
console.log(closestDescendant($2, '.findme')); // $2
console.log(closestDescendant($3, '.findme')); // null
```

```html
<div id="e0">
    <div id="e1">
        <div></div>
        <div id="e4" class="findme"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="e2" class="findme">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="e3">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works, but I've posted an alternative ES6 solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55144581/2441655) since I don't like:
1) The `while` expression having side-effects.
2) Use of the `.matches` check on two lines instead of just one.

Answer (score -1):

Even though it's an old topic I could not resist implementing my closestChild.
Delivers the first found descendant with least traveling ( breath first ). 
One is recursive (personal favorite ), other using a todo list so without recursion as jQquery extensions.

Hope someone benefits.

Note : The recursive gets stack overflow, and I improved the other, now simular to previous answer given.

```
jQuery.fn.extend( {

    closestChild_err : function( selector ) { // recursive, stack overflow when not found
        var found = this.children( selector ).first();
        if ( found.length == 0 ) {
            found = this.children().closestChild( selector ).first(); // check all children
        }
        return found;
    },

    closestChild : function( selector ) {
        var todo = this.children(); // start whith children, excluding this
        while ( todo.length > 0 ) {
            var found = todo.filter( selector );
            if ( found.length > 0 ) { // found closest: happy
                return found.first();
            } else {
                todo = todo.children();
            }
        }
        return $();
    },

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just simply put,

```
$("#find-my-closest-descendant").siblings('.closest:first');
```

Comment: This doesn't always select the current element.

Answer (score -1):

There is an excellent article that points out that what the OP requires can be achieved easily with closest    [Geeks for Geeks]
[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-closest-with-examples/)https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-closest-with-examples/

Answer (score -2):

you have a lot of options, however `$("#parent").children(".child");` is the fastet.
[check this article for details and benchmark](http://aahacreative.com/2010/07/19/jquery-fastest-method-find-descendents/)