# How to selected nested First ul from multiple div

Tags: html, css

Select just the First ul in class area by css

```
<div class='area'>
  <div>
   <ul>     
      <li>
         <ul>
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='area'>
  <div>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <ul>
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='area'>
  <div>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <ul>
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this

`'.area > ul'` # This is not working as `div` is in between the `.area` and `ul`

Is there a different way to select the elements **without referencing the in-between div** in the selector?

So, Finally I should get just 3 `ul` without nested ul's

**Update**

In some other templates of my code the first ul comes after the second level

So to avoid confusion in selector, I am trying to avoid the inbetween divs.

Comment: Your html is invalid to begin with.

Comment: Why can't you reference the in-between div?

Comment: It just that, that changes at different places,As I have many templates. and Sometimes the First Ul comes after the second level. I will update my question to avoid confusions

Comment: So is it just one child level of `<div>` or can there be many? If it's only one level separating the container and target elements, you're fine, but if it's a variable level this can't be done reliably or (particularly) cleanly in CSS

Comment: hmmm. Yes there can be 2 levels at max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you actually had valid HTML, you could use the [`*` wildcard](http://css-tricks.com/things-it-might-be-funuseful-to-try-the-universal-selector-on/) selector, which is as close as you're going to get to "[not] referencing the in-between div". That said, what's wrong with referring to the child `<div>`?:

```
.area > * > ul {
    // Properties
}
```

Using `> *` matches any child tag, so it makes your CSS slightly more flexible, if that's your end goal.

---

For (potentially) two levels of elements, assuming they're `<div>`s, you can do the following:

```
.area > div > ul,
.area > div > div > ul, {
    // Properties
}
```

Comment: Will Give this a try. Will it be able to selected first ul even after the second level?

Comment: I've just posted a comment on your original question. To follow on from it: If there will only ever be a fixed number of levels you'll be fine, but if it can be variable things become a little more difficult

Answer (score -4):

'.area ul' would be the selector you are looking for if your html was correct.

edit:
Sorry, the html is kind of confusing... I thought those were `</ul>s` and that `<ul>s` were overlapping with `<li>s`.

This question my be relevant to your problem:
[Similar to jQuery .closest() but traversing descendants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961770/similar-to-jquery-closest-but-traversing-descedents)

Comment: No, that would select all the ul elements that are descendants of .area, not just the top level ones.