# Change submit button value depending on id of table

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" id="carttable">
<tbody><tr id="carttableheader">
<td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr id="carttablerow0" class="uir-list-row-tr uir-list-row-even">
<td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="extcartborder">blah</td>
<td class="extcartborder">blah</td>
<td class="extcartbordershaded">blah</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" class="extcartborder">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr>
<td class="extcart">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="extcart"><table>
<tbody><tr><td class="textbold" colspan="2">blahblah</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>


<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><span id="tbl_submitter"><input type="submit" name="submitter" id="submitter" value="Submit" style="" class="bgbutton"></span></td></tr>
</tbody></table></td>
 etc. etc..
```

The button at the end now has the value 'Submit' and needs to change to 'Other Text'. I know the table above is old fashioned, ugly, [fill in the blank], but I can't get around that.

I tried this:

```
$('#carttable').closest('#submitter').prop('value', 'Other Text');
```

But it didn't change anything. I looked in firebug's script tab to see what the value was, and it was 'Submit', so that was good, but it didn't replace this. (I know I can do $("#submitter").attr('value', 'Other Text');, but this is also called on other pages, and since #submitter exists there as well, but with a different set up, it would mess it up.. whole story).
Anyway.. why doesn't the call work?

Edit: I have jquery loaded via https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js.
I know it's not the latest, but 1.11 I believe.. but still, .prop works.

Comment: Have you tried just using `.text('Other Text')` instead of `.prop`?

Comment: Or... $('#carttable').closest('#submitter').attr('value', 'Other Text');

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I haven't.. I've tried the last line at the bottom, which uses prop and it worked like a charm. But I need to have it depend on the carttable id.

Comment: @El Guapo I've tried .attr as well, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: The [documentation for .closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) states that it "matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing _up_ through its ancestors in the DOM tree." (emphasis mine). Since you appear to want to traverse _down_ the tree (`#submitter` is contained within `#carttable`), you might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961770/similar-to-jquery-closest-but-traversing-descendants) relevant. Short answer for why your code doesn't work: `$('#carttable').closest('#submitter')` returns an empty set.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks.. that did id: You're right, .closest goes UP the DOM tree, while I needed DOWN.. so I used .find instead, which did the trick

Comment: Since your input has an id why don't you just select it?

Comment: @sebnukem Read the original post...it says: "I know I can do $("#submitter").attr('value', 'Other Text');, but this is also called on other pages, and since #submitter exists there as well, but with a different set up, it would mess it up.. whole story". So.. Yes, I can do that, but it would cause problems on other pages. This was the only page where I had the table with that particular id, so I had to use that dependency.

Comment: @PatrickQ if you wanna migrate that to an answer, I'll give you some love :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following selector should also work for you:

```
$('#carttable #submitter').prop('value','Other Text');
```

(see http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)