# JQuery .each() with daterangepicker has left ALL my daterangepickers broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

In our website, we use [DateRangePicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) for any date and datetime fields.
I applied the following JQuery code to my company's site/testing site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="other_company_start_date[]"]').each(function() {
        $(this).daterangepicker({
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            drops: 'up',
            singleDatePicker: true,
            showDropdowns: true,
            minYear: 2000,
            maxYear: 2030,
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: 'Clear'
            }
        });
    });
    $('input[name="other_company_start_date[]"]').each(function() {
        $(this).on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
            var endDate = $(this).parent().parent().parent().closest_descendent('input[name="other_company_end_date[]"]');
            var yearField = $(this).parent().parent().parent().closest_descendent('input[name="other_company_years[]"]');
            if (endDate.val() != '') {
                var startYear = new Date($(this).val());
                var endYear = new Date(endDate.val());
                yearField.val(Math.abs(startYear.getFullYear() - endYear.getFullYear()));
            }
        });
    });
    $('input[name="other_company_start_date[]"]').each(function() {
        $(this).on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('input[name="other_company_end_date[]"]').each(function() {
        $(this).daterangepicker({
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            drops: 'up',
            singleDatePicker: true,
            showDropdowns: true,
            minYear: 2000,
            maxYear: 2030,
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: 'Clear'
            }
        });
    });
    $('input[name="other_company_end_date[]"]').each(function() {
        $(this).on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
            var startDate = $(this).parent().parent().parent().closest_descendent('input[name="other_company_start_date[]"]');
            var yearField = $(this).parent().parent().parent().closest_descendent('input[name="other_company_years[]"]');
            if (startDate.val() != '') {
                var startYear = new Date(startDate.val());
                var endYear = new Date($(this).val());
                yearField.val(Math.abs(startYear.getFullYear() - endYear.getFullYear()));
            }
        });
    });
    $('input[name="other_company_end_date[]"]').each(function() {
        $(this).on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The divs/inputs are defined with each entry into the database creating another row of input fields (shown below).

```
<div style="border-radius: 5px; border-style: ridge; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
    <h3 style="padding-left: 30px;">Certifications:</h3>
    <div id="wrapper_two" style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <?php
        $atleastonefield = false;
        foreach($certifications as $certification) {
            $atleastonefield = true;
            $certification = explode(":",$certification);
            echo '<div style="display: table-row;">';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 170px;">Certification Name:</label>';
                echo '<input class="formatted" style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: center; height: 40px;" type="text" name="certification_name[]" value="'.(isset($certification[0]) ? $certification[0] : "").'">';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 150px;">Certification Number:</label>';
                echo '<input class="formatted" style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: center; height: 40px;" type="text" name="certification_number[]" value="'.(isset($certification[1]) ? $certification[1] : "").'">';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div style="display: table-row;">';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 170px;">Company Acquired From:</label>';
                echo '<input class="formatted" style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: center; height: 40px;" type="text" name="certification_company[]" value="'.(isset($certification[2]) ? $certification[2] : "").'">';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 150px;">Date Obtained:</label>';
                echo '<input class="formatted" style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: center; height: 40px;" type="text" name="certification_obtained[]" value="'.(isset($certification[3]) ? $certification[3] : "").'">';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 60px;">Expiration:</label>';
                echo '<input class="formatted" style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: center; height: 40px;" type="text" name="certification_expiration[]" value="'.(isset($certification[4]) ? $certification[4] : "").'">';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that on page load, if a box that uses a DateRangePicker is not empty, than the DateRangePicker shows up with NaN as the day options with the month of January and the year of 'minYear'. If the box wasn't empty, it shows the DateRangePicker correctly *even after clicking or manually inputting a date.*

If you noticed the JQuery code is for the "other companies/work experience" fields but the html/php code posted is from the "certifications" fields. The reason for this is the JQuery code is effecting every instance of a DateRangePicker in the 2000-ish lines of code on this page. Last bit of information, the *closest_descendent* is from the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961770/similar-to-jquery-closest-but-traversing-descendants) stack overflow question; however, I doubt that it's related. Really stumped here. Pictures below:

[image: input boxes]
[image: broken DateRangePicker]
[image: working DateRangePicker]

EDIT: Additionally, removing the offending code does **not** fix the issue.

EDIT:

```
<div style="border-radius: 5px; border-style: ridge; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
    <h3 style="padding-left: 30px;">Other Companies You've Worked:</h3>
    <div id="wrapper_three" style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <?php
        $atleastonefield = false;
        $i = 0;
        foreach($other_companies_worked as $other_company_worked) {
            $atleastonefield = true;
            $other_company_worked = explode(":",$other_company_worked);
            echo '<div style="display: table-row;">';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 230px;">Company Name (Related Jobs):</label>';
                echo '<div class="autocomplete companies" style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell; padding: 0; height: 40px;">';
                    echo '<input id="input_'.$i.'" class="formatted" type="text" name="other_company_name[]" value="'.(isset($other_company_worked[0]) ? $other_company_worked[0] : "" ).'" style="text-align: center;">';
                    $i++;
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: right; width: 100px;">Position Held:</label>';
                echo '<div class="autocomplete positions" style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell; padding: 0; height: 40px;">';
                    echo '<input id="input_'.$i.'" class="formatted" type="text" name="other_company_position[]" value="'.(isset($other_company_worked[2]) ? $other_company_worked[2] : "" ).'" style="text-align: center;">';
                    $i++;
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: right; width: 100px;">Years Worked:</label>';
                echo '<div class="autocomplete years" style="width: 40px; display: table-cell; padding: 0; height: 40px;">';
                    echo '<input id="input_'.$i.'" class="formatted" type="text" name="other_company_years[]" value="'.(isset($other_company_worked[1]) ? $other_company_worked[1] : "" ).'" style="text-align: center;">';
                    $i++;
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div style="display: table-row;">';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; padding-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 230px;">Start Date:</label>';
                echo '<div style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell; padding: 0; height: 40px;">';
                    echo '<input id="input_'.$i.'" class="formatted" type="text" name="other_company_start_date[]" value="'.(isset($other_company_worked[3]) ? $other_company_worked[3] : "" ).'" style="text-align: center;">';
                    $i++;
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0; text-align: right; width: 100px;">End Date:</label>';
                echo '<div style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 300px; display: table-cell; padding: 0; height: 40px;">';
                    echo '<input id="input_'.$i.'" class="formatted" type="text" name="other_company_end_date[]" value="'.(isset($other_company_worked[4]) ? $other_company_worked[4] : "" ).'" style="text-align: center;">';
                    $i++;
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, typically jQuery plugins can act on multiple elements in one call, so you should be able to do `$('input[name="other_company_start_date[]"]').daterangepicker(...)`.

Comment: That was the original code however it was only ever working on the first row of fields. All duplicates past the first were affected.

Comment: It seems like your certifications page does not contain any inputs with name='other_company_start_date[]/end_date[]` . So, I don't think that *this* javascript code is affecting them at all.  As you noticed, removing the offending code doesn't fix the issue - so that is *not* the offending code.

Comment: It **is** the offending code. It's the only code that changed. I also updated the question to show that set of code you're asking about @James.

Comment: But if you remove it it's still broken?  Maybe I'm not clear on what you mean by the offending code.

Comment: It seems that the jquery code has influenced every instance of a daterangepicker on the page somehow. Removing it does not rollback the "infected" daterangepickers but it was the only code changed between an intensive testing phase (performed last night and this morning) and this error popping up. I can 100% say that the error "NaN days" error was not there before and was there after the posted jquery was added.